# How to reserve bandwidth for an application?

Tags: windows-7, bandwidth

There are many software, which allows to limit bandwidth for an application, i.e. limit it from above and do not allow an application use more than X Mb/s. Is there a soft, which allows to limit it from below? I.e. don't allow other applications to push the app out and leave it with less than X Mb/s?

To be more specific. I have 10 Mb/s internet, and I would like to be able to always watch 720p videos in a browser, but when other programs do they own stuff and download something, this is not possible. So I want 2.5 Mb/s be always avalable for the browser independently of what other applications wants to do.

Answer (score 1):

There is software out there:  https://www.raymond.cc/blog/restrict-or-limit-internet-download-and-upload-transfer-speed/

I was reading it and it sounds by giving a bandwidth quota, you might actually do more harm than good.

> While this method works, it isn’t dynamic because if you set the download rate on your browser to 100 KB/s while gaming, when you finish gaming more bandwidth will be free but the download will still be 100 KB/s unless you manually change it
>   Read More: https://www.raymond.cc/blog/restrict-or-limit-internet-download-and-upload-transfer-speed/

You will probably want to do something like Killer Ethernet.  Were it sets applications as priorities

I have never used any of these programs from the blog.  I do have the Killer Ethernet hardware and application, that only prioritizes application traffic.  So you would just put the application you are streaming with as Priority 1.  That way it would not get choked by the other things you are doing that are consuming bandwidth.  It is dynamic if that makes sense.
[KillerNetworking](http://www.killernetworking.com/)